# How can i convert this type of array into Object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array of objects:

```
0: {Salami: false}
1: {cheese: false}
2: {mozzarella: false}
3: {mushrooms: false}
4: {Peper: false}
5: {tomatoes: false}
6: {olivs: false}
7: {basil: false}
```

How can i convert it to something like below?

```
{ salami: false, cheese: false, mozzarella: false, mushrooms: false, Peper: false, tomatoes: false, olivs: false, basil: false },
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const object = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(item => Object.entries(item)[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the array of objects, then append each property to a new object, together with its value:

```js
var arr = [
  {Salami: false},
  {cheese: false},
  {mozzarella: false},
  {mushrooms: false},
  {Peper: false},
  {tomatoes: false},
  {olivs: false},
  {basil: false}
];

var obj = {};

arr.forEach(el => {
  var key = Object.keys(el)[0];
  obj[key] = el[key];
});

console.log(obj);
```